# Why clicking on button in React reloading page despite I have event.preventDefault in it?

Tags: reactjs, api, preventdefault

I am very new to React and trying to create my first project, where I created 2 buttons.
One for getting IDs, and the second for sending these IDs for getting actually items by these IDs.
Anyway clicking on the second button is reloading the page, despite that, I have event.preventDefault() in the function body **(displayCocktails)**. Any thoughts on what I am missing?

**Second question**, how I could pass data(return from the first function and then use un second function) between methods in React class component?
I want to use IDs that I got after clicking on the first button, in **(displayCocktails)** function, but I don't how to pass them.
Thank you in advance!

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from './form/index'
import Form2 from './form2/index'
const APIkey = '1'
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: undefined
  }
  getCocktail = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      const ingredient = document.getElementById('input').value
      //https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?a=Alcoholic
      const api_call = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${ingredient}`)
      console.log('first button')
      const data = await api_call.json()
      //https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list
      if (ingredient) {
        //console.log(data)
        // console.log(IDs)
        var cockteilsList = data.drinks.map(el => el.idDrink);
        console.log(cockteilsList)
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    return cockteilsList
  }

  displayCocktails = async (e) => {

    try {
      e.preventDefault()
      const cocktail = document.getElementById('input').value
      console.log(cocktail)
      const api_call = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${cocktail}`)
      console.log('second button')
      const data = await api_call.json()
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div> App component
        <Form getCocktail={this.getCocktail} />
        <Form2 displayCocktails={this.displayCocktails} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;


//FORMS
 
import React from 'react'
const buttonStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 140,
    heigth: 80,
    borderRadius: 15
}
const Form = (props) => (

    <div>
        Press me to get coctail's reccomendation
        <form id='form' style={buttonStyle} onSubmit={props.getCocktail}>
            <input id='input' type='text' name='cocktail' placeholder='Cocktail' />
            <button>Get a recipe </button>

        </form>

    </div>

)
export default Form;


import React from 'react'
const buttonStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: 140,
    heigth: 80,
    borderRadius: 15
}
const Form2 = (props) => (

    <div>
        Press me to get coctail's reccomendation
        <form id='form' style={buttonStyle} method="POST" action="/" onSubmit={props.displayCocktails}>
            <input id='input2' type='text' name='cocktail' placeholder='Cocktail' />
            <button type='submit'>Get a recipe </button>

        </form>

    </div>

)
export default Form2;
```

Comment: could you share your forms component and how you passed your props ?

Comment: already added them, thank you for answering. <br> I already fixed form2, accordingly to the advice below and it works now. But I still don't understand why they were totally the same, but the problem with refreshing was only when I was using form2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first question :

your `displayCocktails()` function probably triggering refresh since its a form, and onSubmit event will trigger refresh to the browser

you want to add to your `onSubmit` event in your form that function, like this
and make sure your button is `type:submit`

`<form method="POST" action="/" onSubmit={this.displayCocktails}>`

Comment: can u pls mark the question as "answered" if that was useful? :)